# combine multiple && conditions into 1

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way in Javascript to do null check on multiple elements I want to

```
a=null; b=null;....n=null;
```

So in total I have 14 variables set to null initially and I want to apply just one solution to all of them if they are ```null``.

```
if (a=== null && b=== null&& c=== null&& d=== null&& e=== null &&...&& n===null){
// set some field to false
}
```

is there a better way to check for null, as this may get cumbersome if we have more arrays added
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a an array of arrays, iterate it using [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and do something if all item values are `null`:

```
if([a, b, c, ... n].every(a => a === null)) {
    // set some field to false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to JS, in JS, values can be "falsey" or "truthy". `if` / `while` / `for` will run if the value it's supposed to evaluates to "truthy." There are few "falsey" values in JS, and the rest are considered "truthy." The false values are:

- `undefined`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `null`
- `''`
- `false`

(I believe I got them all. Think of "six sins": there are six of these)

So check the following code, and what their outcomes are:

```
if(0) console.log('yay') // won't run
if(false) console.log('yay') // won't run
if(null) console.log('yay') // won't run
if('') console.log('yay') // won't run
if(NaN) console.log('yay') // won't run


if([]) console.log('yay') // will run
if('0') console.log('yay') // will run
```

This is a long winded way of saying if you want to do something based on whether array is empty or not, try the following:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
if(arr.length){
  //do stuff if array is not empty
} else {
   // do stuff if array is empty
}
```

Now to actually solve the problem for you, do the following:

```
const masterArray = [a, b, c, d, ... , n];
let length = 0;
masterArray.forEach(subarr=>{
  length += subarr.length;
})

//At this point, if no array had any elements, length would be 0
if(length === 0){
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: so sorry, but I just updated the question and apparently these fields are no longer arrays, they are variables assigned as ```null``` initially and I would like to check for ```null``` values.. sorry for the confusion...thanks!